# Can't get a Signed URL for S3 before knowing the Key

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm letting people post files to my S3 account and I don't know the filename that they'll be posting.

How do I get a signed URL for them ahead of time so they can download whatever file they have posted? I want to do this ahead of time because I don't want to hit my server again.

I'm using the ruby aws sdk.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

You can generate a signed URL from a file that already exists on S3. You can't generate a URL before you know what the URL will be.

Answer (score 0):

While you can't distribute pre-signed URLs without knowing the key, you can use the [S3 POST technique](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingHTTPPOST.html) to generate a signed policy, which can then be used to upload files. This requires building a simple web form, or other tool which can create an HTTP POST request.

Ideally, you would create a separate signed policy document for each user, that way you can revoke access on an individual basis. Also, the policy allows you to constrain the maximum file size, the key prefix, file types and other things.